# Difference between Object.assign and just assign

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know the difference between this:

```
Object.assign(otherObject, {
  someNewProperty: ''
});
```

and

```
otherObject.someNewProperty = '';
```

And.. which one is faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Used that way, there is no difference, the property of the second object is simply copied to the first object. `Object.assign` does however have other uses than just adding a single property. Which is faster probably doesn't matter, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Check here: http://jsperf.com/diff-assign

Comment: crazy @VickyGonsalves !!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you only want to assign a property, use the later. If you want to assign several and don't want to repeat `otherObject.` each time, use the former.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

Whereas `otherObject.someNewProperty = '';` is a method to directly assign a value to some property of an object.

Obviously the `Object.assign` pattern is much slower : [jsperf.com/assign-vs-equals](https://jsperf.com/assign-vs-equals)

Answer (score 9):

For single property, direct assignment (`otherObject.someNewProperty = ''`) is twice faster, but for multiple values - time will grow. Each property + 5% to 10%. Also, code-wise `Object.assign` is nicer for multiple options.

```
Object.assign(otherObject, {
  prop1: '',
  prop2: '',
  prop3: '',
  ...
});
```

VS

```
otherObject.prop1 = '';
otherObject.prop2 = '';
otherObject.prop3 = '';
...
```

You simply can run Profiles tab in Chrome Development tool and run few tests.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is a pretty versatile function that is designed to do complex object composition.

The property dot notation is a straight forward way to assign a single value to a single property.

Regarding which is faster, that's irrelevant considering these are not equivalent, and as one of my [all time favorite posts](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) noted "*asking which one runs faster is maybe a non-starter*".

Answer (score 1):

There is another important thing to show here about the differences between assign directly and using Object.assign(actually, not exactly a difference, but a important thing to be aware).

If you have a Object that's assigned to another variable in JS, like this:

```
const a = { a: 1 }
const b = a
```

then, you decided to use Object.assign to change the value in `a` and assign to another variable(`d`), you will change the value in `b` as well(even you not assigning the Object.assign return to `a`, in this example let's assign to a new variable `d`).

```
const d = Object.assign(a, { a: 2 })
console.log(a) // { a: 2 }
console.log(b) // { a: 2 }
console.log(d) // { a: 2 }
```

Basically, it's important to know that Object.assign will mutate the target object as well all variables pointing to it.

Now, if you use directly the assignment to `d`, it'll not change the value in `a`(and in `b` as well will not change).

```
const d = { ...a, ...{ a: 2 }}
console.log(a) // { a: 1 }
console.log(b) // { a: 1 }
console.log(d) // { a: 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a good question:
We just found a bug, where we would assign properties to a file using Object.assign.

```
const file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
file.name='test'; // does not update the readonly value but doesn't return an error
Object.assign(file,{name:'test'}); // error: 'Cannot set property name of #<File> which has only a getter'
```