# Object.assign vs. assignment operator (i.e. = ) for React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsx

Simple question: I have read a couple of answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241790/difference-between-object-assign-and-just-assign) on the differences between `Object.assign` and the assignment operator (i.e. `=`) and understand all the points brought up such as that the first copies the object while the latter simply assigns the address.

I want to make a decision on which one to use and would like to know what the implications are for React components as I have seen it being done both ways. Is one an antipattern, in the context of React components, which I should not be considering?

An example of my use-case is as shown below:

```
function PageSection({children}) {
    return <div>{children}</div>
}

function Header({children}) {
    return <div>{children}</div>
}

function Body({children}) {
    return <div>{children}</div>
}

// Attach components to the `PageSection` component.
export default Object.assign(PageSection, {
    Header,
    Body,
});
```

And a related question is, is it an acceptable practice to assign to a property of a property i.e.

```
Header.CloseButton = CloseButton
PageSection.Header = Header
```

Comment: What are you assigning to? React component instances? State? Arbitrary JS objects?

Comment: @Rogue Simple React functional components. I have added an example to the question.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the first creates an independent copy, while the second copies the reference, which means that updating the copy will also update the original, hence any copy of its reference, in case of latter. Consider which behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are no functional differences besides readability and *very slight* performance hit by the creation of temporary objects / iterating the enumerable properties (performance difference surely would be negligible to the point where it'd be hard to even measure accurately).

```
const PageSection({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;
const Header({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;
const Body({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

PageSection.Header = Header;
PageSection.Body = Body;

export default PageSection;
```

Is equivalent to

```
const PageSection({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;
const Header({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;
const Body({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

// This performs a function call once `Object.assign()`,
// and you need to create a temp object `{Header, Body}`
// to enumerate and assign to `PageSection`, hence why
// it is technically "less performant."
export default Object.assign(PageSection, {
  Header,
  Body,
});
```

I prefer the first example, because it is much clearer what the intent is.

Answer (score 2):

## (Non-)Idiomatic use of technology

In programming, one concept that is important to development is the ***idiomatic*** use of technology. This means that you should use the programming language or library or building block for what it is intended to be used for, and use it the way it was intended to be used. Aside from avoiding potential issues, using technology idiomatically makes it easier for others to understand your intent, which in turns makes your code easier to maintain.

## Assigning to a React Function Component

A React Component is intended to render HTML. Adding properties to a Function Component is absolutely an anti-pattern because it's not meant to be a generic container and just because you *can* add properties to any Javascript type doesn't mean you *should*.

You haven't explained what you are trying to do. If you're looking for a way to group these 3 related components together, you could put them in a plain object:

```
const BlogComponents = {
    pageSection: PageSection,
    header: Header,
    body: Body,
};
```

## Assignment Operator (`=`) vs `Object.assign()`

As explained above, I don't think we should be adding properties to a React Function Component. But to address the part of your question comparing the two ways of doing things, I can say that

`Object.assign()` is often used to provide default values. That is, you know that you have e.g. 5 different command-line options. Each one has a default value, and you don't know which ones were specified without inspecting the object containing the command-line options that were captured.

You could do:

```
const options = {};
options.isHelp = arguments.isHelp ?? defaultIsHelp;
options.beVerbose = arguments.beVerbose ?? defaultBeVerbose;
```

or:

```
const options = Object.assign({}, defaults, arguments);
```

The latter is much more readable, in my opinion.

Generally, use the assignment operator if you have finite known fields and no defaults.

```
car.doorColor = 'yellow';
car.hasRollbar = false;
```

It might sometimes be convenient to use `Object.assign()` if there are many fields to copy.

## Spread Syntax -- the new `Object.assign()`

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is similar to `Object.assign()`

Rewriting the example above:

```
const options = {...defaults, ...arguments};
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah seems like your suggestion is [what React recommends](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type). However, it would not be possible to use the exported object as a component i.e. in your example I'd also like to use `<BlogComponents></BlogComponents>` I am trying to group components with some nesting structure similar to how [Tailwind does it](https://headlessui.com/react/menu#basic-example) and a lot of other code I've seen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TommyWolfheart correct, the exported plain JS object which contains the Components is not itself a Component. I would suggest trying to train yourself not to want to have a Component which also contains other Components. It will make things complicated if you ever want to use [HOCs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), and, I suspect, in a number of other scenarios. Either way, happy coding adventure!